# How to programmatically set focus for Compose Accessibility Talkback

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility, focus, talkback

I want to focus the original view after the second screen got back press clicked. For example, when I click Legal Button, the app will be navigated to SecondHome Screen. When the SecondHome Screen got back press clicked, it will go to Home Screen. In here, I want to focus and announce the Legal button. But currently, it is reading from top(Account Details) to bottom. **Is there any advice how to achieve this?**

```
@Composable
fun Home(
    navController: NavController,
    lastFocusedItem: MutableState<String?>
) {
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        itemsIndexed(
            listOf(
                "Account Details",
                "Inbox",
                "Transaction History",
                "Payment Methods",
                "Manage Wallet",
                "Merge Accounts",
                "Preferences",
                "FAQ",
                "Customer Support",
                "Legal"
            )
        ) { index, rowData ->
            TextButton(onClick = {
                navController.navigate("SecondHome")
            }, modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                .focusProperties { canFocus = true }
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    if (lastFocusedItem.value == rowData) {
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    }
                }
                .onFocusChanged {
                    Log.d("Testing", rowData + " " + it.hasFocus.toString())
                    if (it.isFocused) {
                        lastFocusedItem.value = rowData
                    }
                }
                .focusable()) {
                Text(text = rowData)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SecondHome(navController: NavController) {
    Button(onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }) {
        Text(text = "Go Back")
    }
}

@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val lastFocusedItemId = remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "Home") {
        composable("Home") {
            Home(navController = navController, lastFocusedItemId)
        }
        composable("SecondHome") {
            SecondHome(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```

Want to focus the view programmatically for Jetpack Compose Accessibility Talkback

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting 'isTraversalGroup = true' and then set the 'traversalIndex' to -1f

for the LazyColumn Modifier

```
Modifier.semantics { isTraversalGroup = true }
```

for the item Modifier

```
Modifier.semantics { this.traversalIndex = -1f }
```

official Android doc [reference here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/accessibility#traversalIndex)